# Nativescript change bottom navigation tab from code

Tags: nativescript, bottomnavigationview

I want to change the active tab of the BottomNavigation which I know I'll be able to do with

```
bottomNav.selectedIndex = 0;
```

problem is defining bottomNav. Here's the structure of the app

App-Root

```
<Frame defaultPage="login/login-page"></Frame>
```

Login page goes to router page containing bottomnavigation

```
<Page actionBarHidden="true" xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
    <BottomNavigation id="bottomNav" selectedIndex="2">
        ...
        <TabContentItem>
            <Frame id="main" defaultPage="categories/categories-page"></Frame> //I want to be here
        </TabContentItem>
        <TabContentItem>
            <Frame id="gallery" defaultPage="gallery/gallery-page"></Frame>
        </TabContentItem>
        <TabContentItem>
            <Frame id="profile" defaultPage="profile/profile-page"></Frame> //I'm here
        </TabContentItem>
    </BottomNavigation>
</Page>
```

In profile page, I have a button to switch to main frame but I can't do it

```
exports.viewProduct = function(args){
    const product = args.object.pid,
    productFrame = Frame.getFrameById('main'),
    bottomNav = Frame.topmost().getViewById('bottomNav'); //undefined

    bottomNav.selectedIndex = 0;
    productFrame.navigate({
    moduleName: 'product/product-page',
        context: { id: product }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check which frame is being returned by `Frame.topmost()`? I believe it should be returning `profile` frame as that's at the top in given point of time. You should rather call your frame by id here,

**XML**

```
<Frame id="root" defaultPage="login/login-page"></Frame>
```

**JS**

```
Frame.getFrameById('root').getViewById('bottomNav') // should do the job
```

Comment: Hi Manoj. You were right, the frame was not right. With ID it works but there's another issue. When I press the back button, the app closes. I suppose the history is being destroyed with this process. How do i fix that?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend discussing an unrelated issue in same SO thread. By default history should work unless you clear it, please create another SO post with details and possibly a Playground sample.